# What could we say about that conjecture that yields P != NP?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, computability, np-complete

Let $F$ be the set of all Boolean formulae.

We say that a Boolean formula $\varphi$ is positive (=monotone) if
$\forall \alpha\in F,i\leq n$, if $\alpha\wedge\neg x_i\models\varphi$, then $\alpha\models\varphi$.

Let $\psi,\xi\in F$. We say that $\psi\vdash \xi$ if $\psi\models \xi$ and $\psi$ is equivalent to a formula $\psi'$ over the connective $\wedge$ only (for example, $\psi'$ could be $x_1\wedge x_2$ but not $x_1\vee x_3$). This is, of course, different from the usual meaning of this notation.

Let $n>1$ and a formula $\varphi:\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}$ that satisfies:

- Positivity
- Almost Linearity
  That is:

$\forall \alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta\in F.
\begin{cases}
\alpha\wedge\gamma\vdash\varphi \\
\alpha\wedge\delta\vdash\varphi \\
\beta\wedge\gamma\vdash\varphi
\end{cases}
\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
(\alpha\wedge\gamma)\vee (\alpha\wedge\delta)\models\beta\wedge\gamma \\
 \ \ \ \ \   \text{or}\\
 (\alpha\wedge\gamma)\vee(\beta\wedge\gamma)\models\alpha\wedge\delta\end{cases}$.

Intuitively, that means that $\varphi$ could not be succinctly written as $\bigvee_i{(\alpha_i\vee\beta_i)\wedge(\gamma_i\vee\delta_i)}$.

============

Let us denote $||\varphi||=\#\{\xi\in F|\xi\vdash\varphi\}$, where here $\#$ stands for set cardinality.

Let us denote by $|\varphi|$ the number of logical gates (=connectives) in the minimal Boolean circuit $C$ representing $\varphi$ over the connectives $\{\vee,\wedge,\neg\}$. This is, of course, the usual definition of minimal circuit size.

============

I am looking for a lower bound on $|\varphi|$ as a function of $||\varphi||$ and $n$.

I conjecture that $|\varphi|\geq {||\varphi||}^{1/\log n}$, but is that true?
Could we say any better?

===========

The *Half Clique problem* (HCP) is: given a graph, does it contain a clique whose length is exactly half of the graph's number of vertices?

HC is a formula that treats its variables as graph edges, and returns "true" iff the assignment to the variables represents a graph with half clique (as defined above).

Let $\xi\in F$ such that $\xi\vdash HC$, so $\xi$ represents exactly one half clique. We denote $V(\xi)$ = the set of vertices that the edges in $\xi$ touch. For example, if $\xi=E_{12}\wedge E_{25}\wedge E_{15}$ then $V(\xi)=\{1,2,5\}$. So clearly if $x\wedge y\vdash HC$, then either $V(x)\subseteq V(y)$ or $V(x)\supseteq V(y)$. Hence, either $x$ or $y$ uniquely defines the Half Clique. From this, the almost linearity trivially follows. Also, clearly HC is positive.

If the above conjecture is true, then we could apply it to $HC$ to get super polynomial lower bound on its size, so $HCP\notin PSize$. Since $HCP\in NP$, we get $NP\ne PSize$, which is known to imply $P\ne NP$.

Comment: [It is claimed (with proof) that HCP is NP-complete in these lecture notes](http://theory.stanford.edu/~trevisan/w4231/fall99/handouts/sol6.pdf). Why do you think it is in P?

Comment: @TomvanderZanden It was a typo. Thanks for the correction!